# Insert Statement not working in java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to insert records in my table.the problem is its giving error like incomplete query .i am not able to figure out the bug here.
Thanks in advance

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String table="student";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Service_Center","","");
PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into "+table+" () VALUES(?,?)");
update.setString(1,"Bhushan");
update.setString(2,"bhushan123");               
update.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Row is added");
```

Comment: You do not need single quote for the table name `'"+table+"'` should be `"+table+"`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty its also not working. returning error like invalid insert syntax :(

Comment: You should also be using query parameters rather than dumping the variable values directly into the query string...

Comment: `user and password` are blank in `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Service_Center","user","password");`

Comment: @BhargavModi Connection is fine, i can retrive records from database using same syntax.. i m facing problem only with insert command

Comment: Better to user prepared statement

Comment: @JonK Thanks, but can you show simple example of how to create a query parameter?

Comment: could you share stacktrace?

Comment: You do something like the following: `st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO some_table (some_varchar_col) VALUES (?)");`, then after that: `st.setString(1, someString);`. Where the 1 is incremented for each additional parameter that you set.

Comment: You should post the exact error. That would be more useful than stating what the error is like

Comment: Bracket or alias the reserved words eg From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335

Comment: @SemihEker Here is my Stacktrace   :                                                                
23-2-2015                                               
3:15
Asus
OS1
Mouse
Mouse
Mouse
Mouse
Mouse not working
Bhushan
Nasik
9028240659
bhushAN@yahoo.com
Deepak Patil
Yes
Nasik
Nasik
300
450.0
300.0
Yes
336.0
Yes
MOuse
MOuse
MOuse
4
300
3.0
10.0
1549.0
Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement
      ("INSERT into "+table+" (Call_Date,Call_Time,.....) VALUES(?,?,.....)");

 update.setString(1,calldate);
 update.setString(2,calltime);
```

Comment: can you give the stacktrace

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
 at basics.DbDemo.main(DbDemo.java:22)

Comment: R u inserting all field's or not ???

Comment: Sr_No is auto)incremented so only that field is not inserted in query, is that a problem?

Comment: `INSERT INTO  "+table+"  VALUES (?,?)` try this

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you have three columns : `From`, `To` and `Source` that are MySQL Reserved words. Hence you will have to put them into backquotes:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT into "+table+" (Call_Date,Call_Time,`Source`,RMA_No,Item_name,Item_MAG,Item_model,Item_SrNo,Booking_Desc,Customer_name,Customer_address,Customer_contact,Customer_email,Call_type,Call_mode,Assigned_to,Service_Charges_Required,Total_Service_Charges,Part_Required,Part_No,Part_Name,Part_Model,Part_Quantity,Part_Price_per_Unit,VAT,LBT,Total_Cost_Of_Part_Requirement,TravellingRequired,`From`,`To`,Distance,TravellingCost) VALUES('"+calldate+"','"+calltime+"','"+Source+"','"+rmaNo+"','"+itemName+"','"+item_MAG+"','"+item_Model+"','"+item_Sr_No+"','"+Booking_Desc+"','"+customer_Name+"','"+customer_Address+"','"+customer_contact+"','"+customer_email+"','"+calltype+"','"+callmode+"','"+assignedTo+"','"+servicetaxApplicable+"','"+totalCharge+"','"+partRequired+"','"+partNo+"','"+partName+"','"+partModel+"','"+partquantity+"','"+price+"','"+vat+"','"+lbt+"','"+total+"','"+travellingRequired+"','"+from+"','"+to+"','"+distance+"','"+expectedTravellingCost+"')");
```

Even better - change these three columns names to non reserved words.....

Comment: MySQL is not used, it is MS Access reserved words that are the problem.